# How to get currently supported language in Android device?

Tags: android, localization, locale

How can we check selected language support on the Android device? or How to get currently supported language in Android device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created one method for checking particular language supported or not.

```
public static boolean isLanSupported(Context context, String text) {        

    final int WIDTH_PX = 200;
    final int HEIGHT_PX = 80;

    int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); 
    Bitmap orig = bitmap.copy(conf, false);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));

    // draw text to the Canvas
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
    int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;

    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
    boolean res = !orig.sameAs(bitmap);
    orig.recycle();
    bitmap.recycle();
    return res;
}
```

following way to call a method

```
 isLanSupported(getActivity(),"ગુજરાતી")
 isLanSupported(getActivity(),"हिंदी")
 isLanSupported(getActivity(),"English")
```

Comment: Not sure how this works! If "ગુજરાતી" is not supported `bitmap` will have some garbage value. It is never same as `orig`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the default language with de **Locale** [object](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)

*Locale.getDefault()* for the default, and *Locale.getAvailableLocales()* for available langages.
([See this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214819/list-all-the-installed-or-supported-languages-in-an-android-phone))

Comment: Thank you J-Jamet for your answer, but it will not work for all language. For example In Nexus device Locale.getAvailableLocales() OR Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales() returns only "Hindi" and "Punjabi" as supporting languages. But this device works fine when select "Gujarati" language in any application.

Comment: Indeed, there are languages ​​that are not officially supported on older versions of the API. Gujarati must have fonts to integrate as root to work. XDA Post : https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2429440 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111764/android-gujrati-and-hindi-supported-application  So sorry for this but you have more work to do for this language.